# Search bar is working AFTER "Cancel Button"

Tags: ios, objective-c, searchbar

I've made a view for editing friend, with a searchbar. My adding/deleting friends is working fine, but I've a problem with my adding/deleting friends WITH SEARCHBAR...
My searchbar finds well the email I'm tapping, but the order change :
if I find 2 email with my searchbar, the 2 email will are the 2 first email in my property "Allfriend", and not the email I found with searchbar...
Is there any code to complete in didSelectRowAtIndexPath after NSLog ?

I let you see my code, tell me if you see a problem :

editfriend.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface EditFriendsViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *allUsers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *currentUser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *friends;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *searchResults;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *user;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filteredArray;


@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *MindleNav;



-(BOOL)isFriend:(PFUser*)user;

@end
```

editfriend.m :

```
#import "EditFriendsViewController.h"

@interface EditFriendsViewController ()

@end

@implementation EditFriendsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.MindleNav];

    self.searchResults = [[NSArray alloc] init];


    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query orderByAscending:@"email"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
            self.allUsers = objects;
            //            self.user = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
            [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }];

    self.currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [self.allUsers count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] email];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = user.email;
    }


    if ([self isFriend:user]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.currentUser relationforKey:@"friendsRelation"];

//Edit Friends with searchbar
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    PFUser *user = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([self isFriend:user]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

        for(PFUser *friend in self.searchResults) {
            if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
                [self.friends removeObject:friend];
                break;
            }
        }

        [friendsRelation removeObject:user];
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.friends addObject:user];
        [friendsRelation addObject:user];
        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }

    [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];

    //Edit Friends
} else {
    PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([self isFriend:user]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        for(PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
            if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
                [self.friends removeObject:friend];
                break;
            }
        }

        [friendsRelation removeObject:user];
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.friends addObject:user];
        [friendsRelation addObject:user];
    }

    [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

}

```
#pragma mark - Helper methods
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email beginswith[c] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResults = [self.allUsers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)isFriend:(PFUser *)user {
    for(PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
        if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: When you find an user your searchbar call `resignFirstResponder` a second time, and you're calling `reloadData` twice.
You shoud fix your code by removing the two lines under "NSLog(@"FOUND USER")

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` on a background thread (due to `findObjectsInBackground`), so your UI won't update right away.

If you want the changes to take place instantly, you need to rewrite that line to:

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

---

Also, since you already do a query for all objects in `viewDidLoad`, when the user would like to search, you shouldn't query again, but instead have a property called `filteredUsers`, which holds the user you'd like to display.

You can filter an array with:

```
self.filteredArray = [self.allUsers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

You can take a look [here](http://www.peterfriese.de/using-nspredicate-to-filter-data/) on how to create an `NSPredicate`.

Comment: I've try to replace [self.tableView reloadData] with [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; but the user doesn't appear after research... :( Is it in "if (!error)" block I've to put in ?
After the "else condition" ? Thanks for replying ! :)

Comment: Every UI update has to be changed to performSelectorOnMainThread. (aka all `reloadData`).

Comment: here is my predicate but don't work again... : - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contains[c] %@",searchText];
    NSLog(@"%@", predicate);
    self.searchResults = [self.allUsers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}

Comment: predicate works fine, but when I find user, my app crash.. :(

Comment: Please edit your question to post code (aka your predicate). Also, saying `my app crashes` is kinda equivalent to calling the firefighters without telling them your address...

Comment: My searchbar finds well the email I'm tapping, but the order change : if I find 2 email with my searchbar, the 2 email will are the 2 first email in my property "Allfriend", and not the email I found with searchbar... Is there any code to complete in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @Viny76 You're really not displaying any effort of trying to debug your code... If you filter your data, shouldn't you be using it?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Now I've debugging my code, that works ! :)
But my last bug is when I search user with search bar, my accessoryType isn't right. I have spent 2 hours for debugging all my code, but accessory type I can't :( Can you help me for finishing this post ? thank you so much !
I edit my post with my lastly code ;)

Comment: I think the code I have to edit is : if ([self isFriend:user]) but I've try to modify isFriend action with self.searchResults but that didn't work :(

Comment: You should post a different question concerning that.